# How to return multiple values in R ShinyServer

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am doing the following:

1. using R ShinyUI, get client inputs on ranges of variables A, B, C;
2. in R ShinyServer, read in a csv file, and using the client inputs to slice the csv, and get the portion that I need;
3. Perform a loop calculation on the csv, calculate various statistics from the loop output, and plot all these statistics.

Pseudo code:

```
data = read.csv('file.csv')

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({ 
  data = data[data$A<INPUT1 & data$B> INPUT2 & data$C<INPUT3,]
  })

 for (i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
   result1[i] = xxx
   result2[i] = xxx
  }


  output$plot <- renderPlot({
  plot(result1)
  })

 })
```

The above code does not work. I want to know:

1. How to correctly incorporate user input and get the variable "data,"
2. How to plot result1 and result2 from output$plot

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not totally clear on your question, but assuming the "INPUT"s are shiny UI elements, you access them with `input$inputname`. To read in a csv you need a `fileInput()` in your UI and something to catch it in server like `data <- read.csv(input$inputname$datapath)`. See here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/upload-file.html

Answer (score 0):

The for loop should be inside a the `renderPlot`, so each time the `input$month` changes, the reactive data will change and then the for lop will update your variables. If you have the for loop outside a reactive expression, it will be executed only once when the app starts, but after changes in the `input`.

Below is simple example based on the pseudo code you provide in your original question to illustrate the possible solution.

```js
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI( fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
      numericInput("input1", "Speed >", 8),
      numericInput("input2", "Dist >", 15)
    ),
    column(8, 
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  dat0 <- cars

  data <- reactive({ 
    dat0[dat0$speed > input$input1 & dat0$dist > input$input2,]
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    s <- dim(data())[1] 
    result1 <- numeric(s)
    result2 <- numeric(s)
    for (i in 1:s){
     result1[i] <- data()[i, 1]
     result2[i] <- data()[i, 2]
    }
    plot(result1, result2)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```